# Migrating from Rails 2 to Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rails 3 deprecated methods and APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648063/rails-3-deprecated-methods-and-apis)

What resources are out there (free or paid) that help walk you through the process of migrating a Ruby on Rails 2 application to Rails 3? I've seen some blog posts (some of which seem out of date) and an eBook for sale somewhere on the RoR website, but what can you recommend as an accurate and complete explanation of what changed from version 2 to version 3 and what needs to be updated when porting to a Rails 3 environment?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648063/rails-3-deprecated-methods-and-apis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aside from a [number of RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/tags/27), on the paid front, BDDCasts has one entitled [Upgrading to Rails 3](http://bddcasts.com/series/urlagg/episodes/upgrading-to-rails-3) for only $5. I can't vouch for the quality of the latter (they have some free episodes too), but Ryan's stuff at RailsCasts is top notch.

[Gregg Pollack's videos](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts/rails3/) on the official site give a great overview as well.

Peepcode also has a [Rails 3 Upgrade Handbook](http://peepcode.com/products/rails-3-upgrade-handbook-pdf) for purchase.

Comment: +9. Ryan's RailsCasts are certainly top notch.

Answer (score 6):

Watch this http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1

Answer (score 3):

According to http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/9/4/ruby-on-rails-2-3-9-released (official Rails blog) it is recommended to first migrate to Rails 2.3.9 - this would help to identify all deprecations and generally get you closer to Rails 3.

BTW, we are also facing the imminent migration to Rails 3, our marketing guys are already horrified! :)

Comment: Cool. We found *something* that will horrify the marketing people! Hopefully they feel as badly horrified as they manage to make us developers feel when they tell a customer a non-existing product will be ready in two weeks. :-)

Comment: Greg, we are probably working for the same company and don't know each other - our marketing people ALWAYS do that: announce release date 2 weeks before the project's start date! :)