# Migrating database (SQLite) from one rails application to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, deployment, data-migration

I currently have a system in which one rails 2.3.2 has a database with all of my content data on. I have since created another application which is using rails 3.1 and is very similar but with some more features (hence changed database structure (added and removed columns around the place)).

My issue is that I'm not sure how to get the data (I only really want three values from all of the "entries" (I don't work with databases often and so don't really know the lingo)) in one of my models from one database (SQLite production) to the other (also SQLite production).
I looked into db:seed however it turns out that rails 2.3.2 doesn't support db:seed and so I cannot use this.

Any ideas on how I can do this and easily add the missing information to these entries aswell (such as the published_at column which is new in the newer application which needs to be added for each entry)?

Best Regards,

Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to migrate the whole application, check this out: [Migrating from Rails 2 to Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781385/migrating-from-rails-2-to-rails-3)

If you only need to manage the sqlite databases, there are a lot of tools to do that. [Here's the complete list](http://sqlite.com/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools)

Comment: I only need to migrate some information from the first database to the second.Can I really do this with these tools? (how?)

Comment: Sure. These with these tools you can perform queries, update data, change the schema, etc. You just need some basic SQL knowledge.