# script/server custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/error (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app build on 1.8.7 and I'm trying to start it on a system with 1.9.3

When I run script/server, I'm getting:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/error (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

My server script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot', __FILE__)
require 'commands/server
```

What am I missing?

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You don't add the origin path of your test. Add in your script to improve the LOAD_PATH

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
$: << File.dirname(__FILE__) + '../..'
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot', __FILE__)
require 'commands/server
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error was due to I was trying to run a Rails 2.1.1 application with Ruby 2.0.0. I solved it by changing to Ruby 1.8.6, which was the one supported by Rails 2.1.1.

If you want to upgrade your Ruby version, you'll probably need to upgrade your Rails application as well. (Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14041449/1924026) for info about Ruby-Rails compatibility.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved by removing the `../` path in the file `/var/www/redmine-2.6.0/config/boot.rb`

```
# Before
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot', __FILE__)
# After
require File.expand_path('../config/boot', __FILE__)
```

I hope it helps.

Marcos Rogerio