# How to fix 'warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I'm trying to run my rails server from RubyMine IDE, I get the error:

```
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
ExitingTraceback
```

I'm currently running Ruby 2.5.5p157 with Rails 4.2.7.1. What should I do in order to run the web app? Thank you very much for your help!

---

Full log when attempting to run the website:

```
C:\Ruby25-x64\bin\ruby.exe "C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Takai/Website/bin/rails" server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development -b 0.0.0.0
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.7.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
ExitingTraceback
 (most recent call last):
C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/Takai/Website/bin/rails: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using an old version of Rails with a newer version of Ruby and Rails wants to use something (`Fixnum`) that doesn't exist anymore in the new version of Ruby.

You have two options:

1. Use a version of Ruby that is supported by your old version of Rails. According to [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087116/which-ruby-on-rails-is-compatible-with-which-ruby-version) Ruby 2.4 should work for you.
2. Update your Rails application to a newer version of Rails that supports Ruby 2.5. Rails 5.1 seems to be the first version of Rails which officially supports Ruby 2.5

The first option is probably much easier. But I still suggest updating your Rails version because your Rails version is unmaintained and will not get any updates or security anymore.

Comment: Do you believe the deprecation warning is actually the issue here? I can't imagine that this warning would cause a stack recursion issue but I cannot confirm or deny it outright.

Comment: I installed Ruby 2.4.5 with Rails 4.2.7.1 but still get the same error. Now instead of getting "Process finished with exit code 1" I get "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"