# Rails slow only with Unicorn / Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn, puma

Running rails 5.0.x, Ruby 2.6.3. And I am having performance problems very specifically when using Unicorn or Puma. Upgrading Rails is going to be quite some work but that's going to be the next thing I'd try.

Basically I look at my logs, the *rails* server responds in about 250ms, pretty consistently.

However when looking from the browser's side, the request takes 1.5-3 seconds. I cannot figure out a way to account for the time disparity.

What makes it extra weird is when I switched from unicorn or puma to webrick the browser's timing is only marginally slower than the time reported by rails, so within 10 or so milliseconds to what rails reported.

I run Puma / Unicorn with 1 thread, 1 process to make an even comparison.

Any suggestions as to what investigation avenues to take would be incredibly helpful.

Edit: Was previously running Ruby 2.4.6

Also tried putting in a default rails app with the same versions, that one works fine without the weird slowdown.

Edit 2: Even started cutting out behaviors and upgrading to latest rails. No help. There's definitely something going on in the configuration / gems, but how to get to an answer?

Edit 3: I use ActiveAdmin. I am suspecting this may be the cause, but need to find a way to prove it.

Comment: I guess you fall in an experimentation area. This thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087116/which-ruby-on-rails-is-compatible-with-which-ruby-version recommends not going further than Ruby 2.4.5 for Rails 5.0

Comment: @Maxence We were running ruby 2.4.6 before I tried all these upgrade paths. But that thread is definitely helpful, I'm digging through documentation looking for any hints.