# rails c (LoadError) from bin/rails:9

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to `rails c` I get the following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
6: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
5: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
4: from /Harsimar.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
3: from /Harsimar.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2: from /Harsimar.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:67:in `console'
1: from /Harsimar.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require_application_and_environment!'
/Harsimar.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require': cannot load such file

/Harsimar.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-4.2.11.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:141:in `require': cannot load such file -- /Users/my_user/Desktop/app/rails-template-master/configs/application (LoadError) 

bin/rails:9 has written => require 'rails/commands'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run an outdated Ruby on Rails application on a current Ruby version. But Ruby on Rails 4.2.x doesn't support Ruby 2.6.

You basically have two options:

1. Downgrade your Ruby version to a version that was still supported by Ruby on Rails 4.2.x. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087116/which-ruby-on-rails-is-compatible-with-which-ruby-version) says that Ruby 2.3 or 2.4 should work.
2. You update your Ruby on Rails application. That means you should try to update to 5.2.x or even better to 6.0.

Because Ruby on Rails 4.2 is not maintained anymore I high recommend starting to update your application.

Comment: now using ruby-2.6.3 with Rails 6.0.0 still having same problem

Comment: did you start a new project from scratch with Rails 6?  are you using a version manager like RVM ?

Answer (score 0):

APP_PATH in my bin/rails was wrong. corrected it to '../config/application' directory
now it works.

Comment: You should not need to change that if you are starting `rails c` from the root of your project.

Comment: Agreed with this. i was starting from root, still finding the RCA for this.