# sprockets requires Ruby version >= 2.5.0 on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have rvm installed on my PC with the default ruby gemset being 2.4.1

```
rvm list
   ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.3 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I want to install rails 5 however `sprockets` fails to install requiring 2.5 ruby. However rails 5 should work with any ruby above 2.2.2:

```
gem install rails -v 5.1.4
Fetching: activesupport-5.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed activesupport-5.1.4
Fetching: actionview-5.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionview-5.1.4
Fetching: actionpack-5.1.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed actionpack-5.1.4
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    sprockets requires Ruby version >= 2.5.0.
```

I don't care about the rails 5 version. The newer the better, but all versions do give me the errors

Any idea why this might happen?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The latest (4.0.0) version of sprockets really requires `ruby >= 2.5.0`. Check it [here](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/v4.0.0/sprockets.gemspec#L42)

Is `gem 'sprockets'` in your `Gemfile` set to a specific version?

To manually change version of sprockets add the line bellow to your `Gemfile`

```
gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.7.2'
```

If you do not have a Gemfile yet try direct installation.

`gem install sprockets -v 3.7.2`

Comment: I do not have a gemfile, the folder is just empty , wanted to do a rails new but for that needed to install rails.

Comment: I do not know why, but this doesn't work for me, but direct sprockets installation from other answer works like a charm

Answer (score 9):

For those that are experiencing this without having it explicitly specified in the gemfile, another workaround is to install the previous version manually:

```
gem install sprockets -v 3.7.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Rails 5 may only require `Ruby => 2.2.2` but if you don't version gems in your `Gemfile` it will always pull down the latest version of the gems. A later gem version then might need a higher version of Ruby.

This however has nothing to do with rails!

Also you might have a Problem with Ruby 2.4.1 using it with Rails 5.1.4

[Which Ruby on Rails is compatible with which Ruby version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087116/which-ruby-on-rails-is-compatible-with-which-ruby-version)