# I am unable to run Rails server using rails s command .It throws an NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu-16.04

When I try to start Rails server, I get following error:

```
22: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
        21: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        20: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        19: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        18: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:73:in `server'
        17: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
        16: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require'
        15: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        14: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:4:in `require'
        13: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        12: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails.rb:11:in `require'
        11: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/application.rb:7:in `require'
         9: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
         8: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/engine.rb:1:in `require'
         7: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         6: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/railtie.rb:2:in `require'
         5: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
         4: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/railties-4.2.10/lib/rails/configuration.rb:2:in `require'
         3: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
         2: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/object.rb:3:in `require'
         1: from /root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:106:in `<top (required)>'
/root/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.10/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:111:in `<class:BigDecimal>': undefined method `new' for BigDecimal:Class (NoMethodError)
```

I am using Rails on Bash in Ubuntu for Windows.

Here are the versions:

- Rails 4.2.10
- Ruby 2.7.1p83
- railties-4.2.10

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to run an old version of Rails on the most recent version of Ruby, but Rails 4.2 is not compatible with Ruby 2.7.

According to "[Which Ruby on Rails is compatible with which Ruby version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087116/which-ruby-on-rails-is-compatible-with-which-ruby-version/51810150#51810150)" downgrading to Ruby to 2.3 or 2.4 should work as a work-around.

Rails 4.2 reached end-of-life some time ago, it is now unsupported and will not get any security updates anymore. I suggest upgrading the Rails version of your application with a high priority.

Comment: Thanks a lot @spickermann ! As a newbie in rails , I am struggling a lot .