# Ruby run project while error how can ı solve this problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Hi ı wanna run ruby project.I write rails server -e development but ı get an error

```
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:270: warning: circular argument reference - now
Traceback (most recent call last):
        13: from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
        12: from script/rails:6:in `require'
        11: from /home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        10: from /home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
         9: from /home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
         8: from /home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
         7: from /home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/config/application.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
         6: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
         5: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
         4: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
         3: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
         2: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
         1: from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:84:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': There was an error while trying to load the gem 'delayed_job_active_record'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `yaml_as' for ActiveRecord::Base:Class
Did you mean?  yaml_tag
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb:4:in `<class:Base>'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb:3:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/delayed_job-4.0.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:64:in `backend='
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/delayed_job_active_record-4.0.2/lib/delayed_job_active_record.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/config/application.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
/home/deployer/apps/isg/20220314091757/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/gems/railties-3.2.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
```

I install node js but doesnt work

Comment: It looks like you want to run Ruby on Rails version 3.2.9 on Ruby 2.5.0. According to the comments and answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9087116/2483313) Rails 3.2 is not compatible with Ruby 2.5. You will need an older version of Ruby. May I ask why you try to use an 10 years old version of Rails?

Comment: @spickermann because the project was started 10 years ago :(

Comment: can u help me for run project? cos ı get an a lot of error... @spickermann

Comment: You need to install Ruby 2.0 and run the app under that.

Comment: I install and run project thank you. @Beartech <3