# Ruby 3.2 + Rails 6.0.2 activesupport error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

I`m trying to create a new Rails app, using Ruby v 3.2.0 and Rails 6.0.2, but I get following error. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

Error image

[image: 1]

Comment: [Please post text, not links to images of text.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby on Rails 6.0 was released before Ruby 3.2 existed. Therefore, it is not surprising that Ruby on Rails 6.0 does not support running with Ruby 3.2

According to the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087116/which-ruby-on-rails-is-compatible-with-which-ruby-version), Ruby on Rails 6.0 should run well on Ruby  2.5–2.7.

I suggest downgrading your Ruby version to the latest 2.7.x version: [`2.7.7`](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2022/11/24/ruby-2-7-7-released/)  was released about two months ago.

But keep in mind that Ruby 2.7 will reach end of life in about two months. Therefore, you might want to consider updating your application to 6.2 or 7.0 soon.